# Is it possible to render specific content from Partial View into main view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view let say `_ABCPartialView` and within my partial view I have two `<div>` tags as below:

```
<div>
//some dynamic stuff
</div>

<div>
<img src="blah blah"/>
</div>
```

Is it possible to render only the second `<div>` which contains an `<img>` tag into my main view?
This method `@html.Partial("_ABCPartialView")` renders all the elements of partial view. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ViewData` to provide arguments to your PartialView. For Sample:

```
@Html.Partial("_ABCPartialView", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "ShowSecondDiv", true } })
```

And inside your PartialView, you just use:

```
<div>

<div>

@if ((bool)ViewData["ShowSecondDiv"])
{
    <div>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: It still renders two `<div>`s. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try using another overload of the `Partial` method. See my edits

Comment: Same results, main view renders the whole partial view.

Comment: Are you passing `true` or `false` to the argument? If you want to hide, you must pass `false` :)

Comment: I want to hide the first div and show the second div, what should I then?

Comment: Abstract and adapt for what you need :). The ideia here is to expose you how to use arguments over the partial views.

Comment: ViewBag is a usable alternative like ViewData  If you want to set data, choose a key for example myKey. And inside the parent, set to it;  ViewBag.myKey = anObjectOrData;   After inside the partial, when you need, call it;  MyClass myKey = (MyClass) ViewBag.myKey;   **Dont forgot to cast type **

Comment: Yeah, the ViewBag encapsulates the ViewData.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a model into your partial which will have a property whether to do that or not. For example:

This is the model:

```
public class YourModel 
{
    public bool ShowDiv { get; set; }
}
```

This is code in your parent view and it passes the info to your partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_ABCPartialView", new YourModel { ShowDiv = false });
```

Inside your partial view check that property and do what you need to do.

```
@if ((bool)Model.ShowDiv)
{
    <div>
         //some dynamic stuff
    </div>
}
```

A partial view can have a model just like a regular view. Also, with a model you get compiler help and intellisence so you do not have to worry about misspellings.

Comment: What is the `ShowDiv` in your partial method? Which `<div>` it is?

Comment: I up voted your answer but because your answer came second I can't accept it as answer although it is a perfect answer.

Comment: No worries. My intention was to show that you can treat it like a regular view and pass a model to the partial with as many properties as you need. And please not that the partial view model can be a property of your parent view's model.